# Wireless Card Driver for Dell Mini 1012 using Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: wireless, dell

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Mini 1012.

It seems to be running fine but I am unable to get my wireless card working?

I even plugged in my Ethernet cable and could not get an internet connection?

Does anyone have any ideas or a how-to? I can't wait to use the new O/S but would like to have internet too! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try with b43. Type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

Since Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal additional installation of the package firmware-b43-installer can be helpful and/or necessary, respectively:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Under the desktop menu System > Administration > Hardware/Additional Drivers, the b43 drivers can be activated for use.

Restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to connect to using wireless OR wired, it might not be just the wireless driver. If you're connected to a wired connection and it's not working, use:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

Comment: Not guaranteed to work,  but a good place to start